# An internal unit of company XYZ provides services to other departments

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

Example 1:
``
Given S="300.01" and B-["300.00", "200.00*,*100.00"].

R[0]="150.00" (=300.01 300.00/600.00) R[1]="100.00" (=150.01* 200.00/300.00)

R[2]="50.01" (=50.01*100.00/100.00)

Example 2 (Pay careful attention to this one).

Given S="1.00" and B=["0.05","1.00"]. 1. First we consider 1.00 because it is the largest,

a. 1.00*1.00/1.05~0.95238...

b. Round 0.95238... to "0.95". Rounding down to carry pennies to smaller departments. c. Set R[1]=0.95. Notice, this is in the same place as 1.00. It is the 2nd value in the result! 2. Now we have 0.05 left

3. Next we look at the smaller B[0]=0.05 department

a. 0.05 0.05/0.05 = 0.05 b. No rounding required

c. Set R[0]=0.05. R=["0.05", "0.95"]
`

Write a function:

class Solution { public String[] solution(String 5, String[] B); }

that, given a string S representing the total excess billables and an array B consisting of K strings representing the undiscounted bills for each customer. The return value should be an array of strings R (length M) in the same order as B representing the amount of the discount to each customer.

Notes:

1. The total S should be completely refunded. Neither more nor less than S should be

returned. Don't lose or gain a penny!

2. Be careful with the types you choose to represent currencies. Floating points numbers are notoriously error prone for precise calculations with currencies.

Test Output

3. Amounts should be rounded down to the nearest $0.01. By design, fractional pennies are pushed to groups with smaller unadjusted invoices.
4. Results should be represented with 2 decimal places of precision as strings, even if these are both zeroes. ex. "100.00" 5. You may assume sensible inputs. The total to be discounted will never exceed the total of the

unadjusted invoices.

6. Please do pay attention to returning the discounts in the same order as the incoming invoices.

Answer:::

```
def solution(A):
answer = 0
current_sum = 0
#Currently there is one empty subarray with sum 0
prefixSumCount = {0:1}

for list_element in A:
    current_sum = current_sum + list_element
    if current_sum in prefixSumCount:
        answer = answer + prefixSumCount[current_sum]
    
    if current_sum not in prefixSumCount:
        prefixSumCount[current_sum] = 1
    else:
        prefixSumCount[current_sum] = prefixSumCount[current_sum] + 1

if answer > 1000000000:
    return -1
else:
    return answer
```

#Sample run

A = [2,-2,3,0,4,-7]

print(solution(A))

Comment: There is no question here. Just a dump of what looks like poorly formatted homework.

Answer (score 1):

**strong text**

Find my solution for JavaScript

You can avoid function sumArray and use the sum funciton with reducer within solution function.

```
enter code here



function solution(S, B) {
    // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)

      

      let copyArray=[...B];
        let solutionObj={};
  
  
  //ordered array to consider last first
      copyArray.sort();
  
//calculating sum of values within array
  let sumArray=B.reduce((acc,value)=> acc+Number(value),0);
  

  //calculating values of array
  //loop for ading on to solvin array
  let initial=S;
  for(i=copyArray.length-1;i>=0;i--){   
    //obtaining index of value addded to solution array
    let index=B.indexOf(copyArray[i]);
    let value=initial*copyArray[i]/sumArray;
    
    value=i==0?Math.ceil(value*100)/100:Math.floor(value*100)/100;
    
    solutionObj[index]=value.toFixed(2);

  }
  

  return Object.values(solutionObj) ;

  }


  
console.log(solution(300.01,["300.00","200.00","100.00"]))

console.log(solution(1.00,["0.05","1.00"]))
```

[These are the resulting entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qYb5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solution in java for the same coding exercise

```
public String[] solution(String S, String[] B) {

        List<Double> list = Arrays.stream(B).sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(v->Double.valueOf((String) v)).reversed()).map(Double::parseDouble).collect(Collectors.toList());

        Double S1 = Double.valueOf(S);

        String R[] = new String[B.length];
        Double total = 0.00;


        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            Double individualValue = list.get(i);
            Double sumTotal = 0.0;
            for(int j = i+1;j < list.size(); j++){
                sumTotal+=list.get(j);
            }
            BigDecimal data = new BigDecimal(S1 * (individualValue / (individualValue + sumTotal)));
            data = data.setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
            total+=data.doubleValue();
            R[i] = String.valueOf(data);
            S1 = S1 - Double.valueOf(R[i]);

        }
        Double diff = new BigDecimal(Double.valueOf(S) - total).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).doubleValue();
        if (diff > 0) {
            R[B.length - 1] = String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(R[B.length - 1]) + diff);
        }
        return R;
    }
```

Comment: This code snippet fails for the test case 

Example test:   ['1.00', ['0.05', '1.00']]
WRONG ANSWER (got ['0.95', '0.05'] expected ['0.05', '0.95'])

Comment: That is suppose to be the answer as we need to sort out the values

Comment: The codility unit test did not agree - regardless it passed 10 out of 13 unit tests overall